# Suspend shuts down my laptop

Tags: release-loki, suspend, shutdown, power

My laptop (Dell XPS 13) started shutting itself off every time I closed the lid. At first, I thought that maybe something was changed in my power settings but lo and behold, it's set to suspend when the lid is closed.
I just pressing suspend in the power drop menu from the top bar and the same thing happened, the laptop simply shut itself off.
Can someone help me out with this? I'm using Elementary OS Loki, fully updated and everything.
Thanks!

Comment: I have never had luck with the suspend and hibernation settings of Elementary OS. I just stick to turning on and off the system without using any special power options inbetween. I think it must be hard to have drivers for all of the different power regulators for these devices. --meant to make this a comment, not an answer.    The point of it is to show that sometimes it just does not work and you have to work around it.

Comment: I can report the same thing in another Dell, just a different model: Inspiron 7560. Mine also shuts itself off on battery if the headphone is connected. None of this things happens on Windows. I've been searching for an answer to this and found that another Dell users have been [experiencing similar problems with Mint](https://tutel.me/c/unix/questions/362251/system+crashes+when+headphones+are+connected+while+on+battery+power+linux+mint+18).